# Parse VSTest output in Github Action and use as a YAML variable

Tags: xaml, github-actions, vstest, coverlet

I'm SOOO close to having this working, but I don't know enough yaml-foo to see a solution.

It's clear that there's no way to tell coverlet (https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet) to NOT use a random GUID in the results path:

[image]
(from https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/master/Documentation/VSTestIntegration.md).

I'm doing a bunch of code coverage reporting and as part of that, I want to generate a GitHub badge for the project using https://github.com/simon-k/dotnet-code-coverage-badge.

My build workflow:

```yaml
name: Build Terminal.Gui with .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.100

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore

    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"  --settings UnitTests/coverlet.runsettings

    - name: Create Test Coverage Badge
      uses: simon-k/dotnet-code-coverage-badge@v1.0.0
      id: create_coverage_badge
      with:
        label: Unit Test Coverage
        color: brightgreen
        path: UnitTest/TestResults/<uuid>/coverage.opencover.xml
        gist-filename: code-coverage.json
        # https://gist.github.com/migueldeicaza/90ef67a684cb71db1817921a970f8d27
        gist-id: 90ef67a684cb71db1817921a970f8d27
        gist-auth-token: ${{ secrets.GIST_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

The badge tool needs a path to the opencover.xml file. I can generate the file just fine, but it ends up on a folder `UnitTests/TestResults/<UUID>/coverage.opencover.xml`.

Per the above, I can't (yet, apparently) change VSTest's behavior. So I need to figure out a way of capturing that UUID in the output into a variable and using it in `path:`.

That UUID is sitting right there in the test run results and I just need to somehow grab it:

[image]

Is this possible? Or, is there some way to do a copy command using a wildcard that would copy the contents of `UnitTest/TestResults/*/` to somewhere deterministic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out and am answering my own question in case some other YAML noob has a similar question:

*Just use the Linux mv command to move the file:*

```yaml
- name: Test
      run: |
        dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"  --settings UnitTests/coverlet.runsettings
        mv -v UnitTests/TestResults/*/*.* UnitTests/TestResults/

    - name: Create Test Coverage Badge
      uses: simon-k/dotnet-code-coverage-badge@v1.0.0
      id: create_coverage_badge
      with:
        label: Unit Test Coverage
        color: brightgreen
        path: UnitTests/TestResults/coverage.opencover.xml
        gist-filename: code-coverage.json
        # https://gist.github.com/migueldeicaza/90ef67a684cb71db1817921a970f8d27
        gist-id: 90ef67a684cb71db1817921a970f8d27
        gist-auth-token: ${{ secrets.GIST_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```